# Why aren’t the electric and magnetic components of an EM wave complementary?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, classical-field-theory

Every visualization of an electromagnetic wave is essentially some variation of this picture:

[image: from Wikipedia]

In every one of these graphs, both the electric and magnetic components are shown as being sine waves with the same phase angle. However, it is just as frequently stated that the amplitude of a magnetic field is related to the *derivative* of the electric field at any given point in space and/or time. Shouldn’t it follow, then, that the magnitude of any given point along the magnetic wave should peak when the corresponding point along the electric wave is at 0? In other words, if the electric component of an EM wave were a sine wave (with no phase angle), shouldn’t the magnetic component be a cosine wave (also with no phase angle)?

Comment: Have you searched this site for answers to similar questions? There are quite a few. For example:  [Phase Relationship between Electric Field and Magnetic Field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290730/9887), and [If time-varying electric and magnetic fields originate each other, how come they are in phase?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358941/9887) and [Phase-alignment in EM-waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285718/9887). This is not an exhaustive list.

Comment: As an aside, consider what the implication is for energy transport if the electric field is in quadrature with the magnetic field.

Comment: Your picture is for the linear polarization, which  is a superposition of two opposite circular polarizations (pure states of the photon’s spin). The fields are at 90 degrees in the circular polarization. Thus your question is not well defined.

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful for you to read the last paragraph of my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon) and the question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/492020/maxwell-equation-similar-to-a-solution-for-a-standing-wave-in-a-box)

Answer (score 5):

Maxwell's equations relate spacial derivatives with time derivatives, e.g.
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$
So your assertion

> However, it is just as frequently stated that the amplitude of a
>   magnetic field is related to the derivative of the electric field at
>   any given point in space and/or time

is false.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Felipe!. Note that OP doesn't assert that, what OP claims is frequently stated, is *true* but, rather, that it is frequently stated. That may be false too but you haven't proved it.

Answer (score 2):

Equations of the form below are solutions of the wave equation:

$\mathbf E = \mathbf E(u)$, and $\mathbf B = \mathbf B(u)$, where $u = \mathbf {k.x} – \omega t + \theta$, $\omega = |\mathbf k|c$, where $\mathbf k$ is a constant vector and $\theta$ is a constant.

The expression for $u$ means:
$u = k_xx + k_yy + k_zz - ωt + θ$ and $|\mathbf k| = (k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2)^{1/2}$

They are called plane waves because for a given value of $t$ and $u$, the expression above for $u$ is an equation of a plane normal to $\mathbf k$.

Using that general equation for a plane wave, and doing the derivatives, it is possible to prove:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf E = \left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right)\left(\mathbf k \times \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right)\frac {\partial (\mathbf k \times \mathbf E)}{\partial t}$$

According to one of the Maxwell equations:
$$\nabla \times \mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}$$

It follows that:
$$ -\left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right) \mathbf k \times \mathbf E = \mathbf B$$

We conclude that $\mathbf B$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf k$ and $\mathbf E$. But also that, as $\mathbf k$ is a constant vector, and has a constant angle with $\mathbf E$, that $|\mathbf E|$ is always proportional to $|\mathbf B|$.

If we suppose $\mathbf E = \mathbf E(u)$, and $\mathbf B = \mathbf B(u+\alpha)$, the only way to get that is making $\alpha = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For a traveling plane wave E and B are in phase. For a standing plane wave they are 90 degrees out of phase. This follows from the Maxwell equations.

Comment: “*For a traveling plane wave E and B are in phase.*” - For the circular polarization (a pure state of a photon) they are at 90 degrees, are they not?

Comment: @safesphere they are not; the 90deg phase shift is between the horizontal and the vertical components of the E (or B) fields., the *same* components of the field, that is $E_x, B_x$ and also $E_y, B_y$, are in phase.

Comment: Not according to this: “*If you pick some direction to measure the fields along, the components of E and B along that direction have a 90° phase shift with respect to each other. A phase shift of 90° means that as E peaks B becomes zero, and as B peaks E becomes zero.*” - https://sureshemre.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/is-there-a-phase-difference-between-electric-and-magnetic-field-oscillations-of-an-electromagnetic-wave/amp/

Comment: @safesphere Circular polarisation can be seen as the sum of the two linear polarisations with 90 degrees phase shift between them. For each linear polarisation E and B are in phase. Thus it is seen that the same is true for the circular polarisations.

Comment: Are you saying the source quoted above is incorrect?

Comment: @Either that it was not quoted correctly.

Comment: @safesphere, think of how a quarter-waveplate converts linear polarized incident light to circular polarization. The polarization vector of the incident light needs to be at 45 deg to the fast axis of the waveplate so that the orthogonal components are equal in magnitude. This introduces a 1/4 wave (90 deg) phase shift *between the orthogonal components of the electric field*. The magnetic field components get the same relative phase shift so the E & B fields are in phase component wise. Are you familiar with the [Jones calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus)?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Thanks for the info, I appreciate it.

Comment: @my2cts Are you accusing my computer of censoring the copy/paste operation? Dammit! I know Microsoft has been watching over my shoulder - LOL!

Comment: The proof is in one of my comments above. Of course the B field is 90 degrees rotated, so when the rotation is concerned it is 90 degrees out of phase. When the propagation is concerned it is in phase. Would this solve the c/p issue?

Answer (score 0):

after some research it seems difficult for me to give a comprehensive answer. But here are the key notes:

- The displayed pictures, where $E$ and $B$ are in phase are correct for the $\textbf{far field}$ --> So look up near and far field
- The $\textbf{curl}$ of  $E$ and $B$ are related to the time derivatives of $B$ and $E$, respectively. So that involves also a derivative in space.

Here the math that might interest you (from https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektromagnetische_Welle):

\begin{align}
  \vec{E}& = \vec{E}_0 f(\vec{k}\vec{x}-ct)  \\
  \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = \vec{k} \times \vec{E}_0 \frac{\partial f(\vec{k}\vec{x}-ct) }{\partial (\vec{k}\vec{x})}& = -\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t} \\
\text{with} \qquad  \frac{\partial f(\vec{k}\vec{x}-ct) }{\partial (\vec{k}\vec{x})} &= - \frac{\partial f(\vec{k}\vec{x}-ct) }{\partial (ct)} \\
\text{follows} \qquad \vec{B} &= \frac{1}{c} \vec{k} \times \vec{E}
\end{align}