# Exceptions for Plane Waves Rules

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Let's consider plane waves propagating along $z$ direction, namely wave of this form: $\vec E(ct\pm z)$,$\vec B(ct \pm z)$.
On my book there is a derivation that shows the following relations are true for such waves ($\vec C$ intensity and direction are those of the speed of light in vacuum):

$$\vec E=\vec B \times \vec C$$ $$\vec E \cdot\vec B=0$$

I tried to use the linearity of the Maxwell equations to see if the general solution $\vec E(ct + z)+\vec E(ct - z)$ satisfies the above relations and it seems that it's not always true, however, I may have done some error.

My question is, are the above equations valid for all the plane waves,
$\vec E=\vec E(z,t)$, $\vec B=\vec B(z,t)$?

Comment: you can use fourier transforms to decompose any signal E(z,t) into linear combination of  sinusoidal waves and use the linearity of Maxwell's equation to treat each sine wave individually

Comment: I don’t understand, how is this suppose to help me?

Comment: Can you specify what $C$ and $\mu_k$ is?

Comment: I anwered a related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/553880/195949